# Como liberar um sub-diretório protegido com .htaccess?

Tags: php, htaccess, cakephp

Tenho um `.htaccess` no meu ambiente de teste desenvolvido em CakePHP e no .htaccess tem autenticação para não ser qualquer um a acessá-lo.

Agora preciso liberar um diretório do site, na verdade um plugin do CakePHP, preciso que qualquer pessoa tenha acesso sem ser necessário autenticação.

```htaccess
<Directory /home/meusite/app/webroot>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Ambiente de Desenvolvimento Teste"
  AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user

  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

## Pergunta

Como posso libertar um sub-directório de um directório protegido pelo `.htaccess` em cima apresentado?

Comment: Não seria mais interessante ao invés de tratar isso no .htaccess você criar um sistema de autenticação no CakePHP?

Comment: Poderia postar o código que está utilizando para bloquear o acesso?

Comment: Primeiramente, você deve postar seu .htaccess para entendermos como está fazendo o bloqueio.

Comment: @KennyRafael não preciso, pois é um ambiente de testes apenas. O Ambiente de produção está operando normalmente, e o .htaccess é mais rápido de ser feito. O código do meu htaccess está na pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adicione ao arquivo de configuração (geralmente o `httpd.conf`):

> **Nota:** `<Directory ...>...</Directory>` não se adicionado diretamente ao arquivo `.htaccess`

```htaccess
<Directory /path/to/dir/protected/unprotected>
     Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

Fonte: [@atonyc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7139265/1604223).

Comment: Mesmo no cakephp funciona assim?

Comment: Essas configurações são do Apache.

Comment: Penso que a ideia será criar um ficheiro `.htaccess` na raiz da directoria que deve ficar sem protecção de password e aplicar nesse ficheiro o conteúdo da resposta.

Comment: Infelizmente não rolou... Tentei colocar direto no sites-available no servidor, e tbm tentei colocar no .htaccess no diretório que eu queria sem proteção. Será que pode ser algo do CakePHP, estrutura de pastas, ou algo do tipo?

Comment: @Artur `Directory` não funciona com `.htaccess`, tem que configurar no `httpd.conf`, como o Calebe mencionou, *adicione ao arquivo de configuração*, vou editar para ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 2):

Adicione as seguintes configuração

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/{nomedosite}.*$ noauth=1
Allow from env=noauth
Satisfy any
```

Troque o {nomedosite} para o caminho que espera vir na URL.

Seu .htaccess ficaria assim

para /home/meusite/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Ambiente de Desenvolvimento Teste"
  AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user

  SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/meusite.*$ noauth=1

  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  #AllowOverride All
  #Order Deny,Allow
  Satisfy any
  Deny from all
  Allow from env=noauth

  # Aqui vem as configurações do .htaccess padrão do CakePHP
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Existe outros htaccess fora da pasta webroot, fique atento para isso.

Caso queira listar os arquivos dentro da pasta liberada adicione o código abaixo que faz com que as regras do htaccess sejam ignoradas para a pasta especificada.

```
RewriteRule ^meusite.*$ - [PT]
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978080/htaccess-exclude-one-url-from-basic-auth