# Forbidden quando acesso meus diretórios - Apache

Tags: apache, windows, http-status-code-403

Estou utilizando Windows 7 x64 e instalei o apache 2.4 com o PHP 7.1 separadamente, configurei tudo e quando coloco localhost, funciona normalmente.

Então dentro do meu htdocs, criei uma pasta chamada projetos. Quando eu acesso o endereço http://localhost/projetos/ ele me retorna 403 forbidden e não me mostra os arquivos que eu tenho nele, o que eu posso fazer para liberar o acesso ?

OBS: Não utilizo WAMP e XAMP, só apache e php nativo.

**UPDATE**

Meu httpd.conf está assim:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"

<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options ExecCGI
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

E estou usando vhosts, httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/projetos/vhost.com/"
    ServerName vhost.com
    <Directory  "c:/Apache24/htdocs/projetos/vhost.com">
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa liberar o acesso as subpastas por meio do arquivo `httpd.conf` localizado dentro da pasta de Conf no diretório de instalação do apache.

Ou adicionar uma regra no seu arquivo `.htacces`, bom pros dois casos você pode pesquisar nessa outra pergunta aqui em baixo que tem a solução.

[Como liberar um sub-diretório protegido com .htaccess?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1710/como-liberar-um-sub-diret%C3%B3rio-protegido-com-htaccess)

Comment: Como faço isso por httpd.conf ?

Comment: antes desse `<Directory "..htdocs">` há outro `<Directory />`, nele informe apenas `AllowOverride none` e `Allow from all`, se não der certo coloque todo seu arquivo httpd.conf na pergunta.